# soundcloud api returns a track with tag_list always missing first tag

Tags: soundcloud

I am building a small web app for managing my audio library based on tags. I edit a track on SoundCloud, entering tags: #abc #def #ghi. I hit the tracks endpoint in the app I am developing: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?[...]

The track returned has a tag_list containing def and ghi but never the first tag (abc).

Is anyone else experiencing this? I have checked the XHR response in chrome dev tools and the tag is missing there.

Comment: Yes I've noticed the exact same issue happening. Seems like a pretty major bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed may be a bug with SoundCloud, but you will notice that your first tag shows up under `genre`, and the rest of your tags show up under `tag_list`.

Comment: I never noticed that. This almost makes sense, especially considering that they require that one tag to upload a track. Thanks!